# Que sentido para o nome "Amanda" entende intuitivamente um falante nativo?

Tags: significado, nomes, gerúndios

Eu *já conheço* o significado do nome Amanda; explicarei isso mais à frente.
A minha dúvida específica é:

- Que sentido entende um falante nativo, quando olha para o nome "Amanda"?

Estou perguntando dessa forma "o que você sente" por que eu mesmo posso ir na Internet e ler o que é a opinião tradicional sobre o significado. Mas eu tenho as minhas dúvidas e não acredito simplesmente no que todo mundo fala.

Então vamos fazer o teste antes de conferir o Wikipedia, etc.?
Eu imaginaria que o significado fosse:

1. Amanda feminino de Amando a quele que vive amando, assim Amanda quem esta amando, que ama muito, que tem muito amor.
2. Amanda quem esta sendo amado, quem é muito amável, quem tudo mundo ama.

Você já pode adivinhar que eu acho o número 1 a explicação certa, e o número 2 é o que eu li na Wikipedia mas em que não acredito. A meu ver, nada teria parado alguém de dar o nome "Amada" para significar aquele que está sendo amado por tudo mundo, que é amável. Mas para mim, o "n" de Amanda vira o amor ativo, que é ela quem ama.

Cuidado! Buraco de Coelho!

Agora eu tento provar de uma vez que estou certo, e daí caiu tudo em que eu acreditei até agora sobre o gerúndio. Vamos lá:

Primeiro, sabendo que o nome vem do latim, com o bispo Amando de Maastricht (584-675) sendo o mais antigo exemplo que eu achei desse nome, eu fui ver a forma gramatical em latin próprio.

O [conjugador latim do verbo "amo"](https://www.verbix.com/webverbix/go.php?T1=amo&D1=9&H1=109) me disse que existem essas duas formas:

> - Gerund: amándum
> - Gerundive: amándus

Observe que o genus é neutro no gerúndio, mas o mais próximo do nome do bispo é uma forma chamado "gerundive" em inglês.

Então fui ver [o que significa e como funciona esse "gerundive"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerundive). Não achei na Wikipédia portuguesa, então aqui vai em inglês:

> In Latin grammar, a gerundive (/dʒəˈrʌndɪv/) is a verb form that
> functions as a verbal adjective.
>
> In Classical Latin, the gerundive is distinct in form and function
> from the gerund and the present active participle. In Late Latin, the
> differences were largely lost, resulting in a form derived from the
> gerund or gerundive but functioning more like a participle. The
> adjectival gerundive form survives in the formation of progressive
> aspect forms in Italian, Spanish and Brazilian Portuguese and some
> southern/insular dialects of European Portuguese. In French the
> adjectival gerundive and participle forms merged completely, and the
> term gérondif is used for adverbial use of -ant forms.[1](https://www.verbix.com/webverbix/go.php?T1=amo&D1=9&H1=109)
>
> There is no true equivalent to the gerundive in English; the closest
> translation is a passive to-infinitive non-finite clause such as books
> to be read. That reflects the most common use of the Latin gerundive,
> to combine a transitive verb (such as read) and its object (such as
> books), usually with a sense of obligation. Another translation is the
> recent development of the must- prefix as in a must-read book.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerundive)

E que supresa! Não somente o último parágrafo está dando razão a essa interpretação de Amando como "person to be loved" (quem deve ser amado) mas o segundo parágrafo está derrubando tudo que eu pensei que entendi sobre a diferença de, por um lado, o gerúndio, o aspecto progressivo, the present continuous, que sempre em português está formado com o suffix -*x*ndo com *x* sendo o vocal de tronco do verbo (a, e, ou i), e por outro lado, o particípio passado ou passivo, com o sufixo -*x*do (sem "n").

De repente eles estão dizendo que isso é apenas uma coisa do português brasileiro e nem o português europeu tem isso?

Desculpem mas eu não acredito nisto, porque é uma regra que funciona do mesmo jeito em espanhol também. Eu já estive em Portugal e não reparei em nenhuma diferença sobre o uso do gerúndio.

O francês está dificultando a situação, com o jeito deles de cortar as coisas ficando com apenas uma forma para os dois: "amant".

Então agora estou bastante confuso. Eu ainda penso que "Amando" é aquele que vive amando, não principalmente quem deve ser amado.

Reiterando:

- Que significado para o nome "Ammanda" entenderia, intuitivamente, um falante nativo?

Comment: *"Amanda feminino de Amando"* desculpa mas isso não faz sentido, quer dizer que "casa" é feminino de "caso"? são coisas diferentes, se pensar em nome, o mais "próximo" seria Armando, que não é necessariamente o masculino de Amanda. Alguns nomes tem sim um equivalente no outro genero, mas nesse exemplo da pergunta acho que não se aplica

Comment: @RicardoPontual, com nomens isso faz muito sentido. Giovanna é feminino de Giovanni, etc. Muitos e muitos exemplos.

Comment: sim eu sei, como Paulo e Paula, mas me diga, quantas pessoas conhece que se chamam "Amando"? :) Algums nomes não tem um relativo no outro gênero, por exemplo Henrique ou Fátima

Comment: @RicardoPontual, o primeiro, Amando de Maastricht, eu escrevi sobre isso mesmo na minha pergunta. Não leu?

Comment: sim eu li Gunther, mas conhece quantos em países falantes de lingua portuguesa?  Esse Amando é francês :) Eu entendo o seu ponto, mas estou pensando na pergunta sobre o ponto da lingua portuguesa, que é o foco aqui, e a comparação para mim não faz sentido porque não conheço pessoas com o nome Amando, seria o mesmo com Paul, entende o que quero dizer? o nome Clara, não posso dizer que o masculino seria Claro, não conheço pessoas com esse nome, nem no Brasil nem em Portugal, é isso que estou querendo dizer

Comment: @RicardoPontual desculpe mas o que não faz sentido é sua tentativa a ridicularizar a pergunta, e eu vou dizer isso é ignorante -- não na forma colloquial que brasileiro usa a palavra ("enqnorante" rsrsrs) mas no sentido original. Por que com os poucos anos que eu tenho no brasil, eu já conheci um cara chamado Amando, ele queria arrendar um immóvel que eu tinha.

Comment: *"tentativa a ridicularizar a pergunta"* onde eu fiz isso? eu só disse que a comparação não faz sentido, em momento nenhum ridicularizei nada, estou dando exemplos concretos justificando minha opinião. Não pretendo mais discutir isso, a pergunta é sua, continue com o seu ponto, paramos por aqui não há mais o que se discutir, boa sorte

Comment: @RicardoPontual, acho que o Gunther disse “ridicularizar” no sentido de fazer parecer ridículo. Não sei se o Gunther checou se “Amanda” é realmente feminino de “Amanda”, mas o gerundivo se flexionava em gênero, então, acho que é um ponto sem muita importância.

Comment: @GuntherSchadow, editei a pergunta para a tentar tornar mais clara. Por favor revê as edições: achas que a pergunta manteve o espírito e intenção de pergunta que tens?

Comment: Inicialmente não tinha lido com atenção e tinha percebido errado o que tentavas perguntar. Mas agora continuo confuso. Os nomes normalmente não significam nada, e são desconexos do seu significado semântico original. Quando alguém diz "Pedro", ninguém associa a rocha ou a pedra ou a resistente...é só um nome. Quando alguém fala da Rosa Luxemburgo, raramente se pensa ou associa a uma flor. Então, é-me difícil entender o que perguntas... estás talvez a tentar perguntar a que significado eu associaria o nome "Amanda", **se tentasse** procurar-lhe um significado? (Intuitivamente, sem dicionários.)

Comment: Não entendemos nada especial, apenas um nome, sem significado algum além de um nome, a menos quando estamos curiosos é que procuramos saber o que o nome da pessoa pode significar.

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil, se eu ouco "Rosa" de Rosa Luxemburg, sendo falante nativo de alemão eu penso a flor com certeza. Nos sentimos o sentido dos nomens, especialmente quando os nomens se referem a substantivos. Exemplo, em Inglês é commun usar nomens como "April", "Hope", ou "Autumn" e como eu sou fluente em inglês, eu ouço o mes, a esperança e o otono, sim. 

Falar que "nome é apenas nome sem significado algum além de um nome" é ignorante.

Comment: @GuntherSchadow, acho que ligar o nome com um significado é algo que varia. Eu, ANeves e Archerspk vemos nomes desse mesmo jeito, que nomes são apenas substantivos próprios sem significado extra. E pela minha experiência e pelas várias pesquisas no Google sobre o significado dum nome, creio eu que muitos, senão a maioria, dos brasileiros vêem assim também. Acho que o ANeves apenas falou sua experiência e visão pessoal, não querendo bater o martelo.

Comment: Não tem mal nenhum, já me chamaram pior que ignorante. Essa ao menos tem boa solução, vou ler mais. :) Mas, Gunther, então e a pergunta que tentei fazer com o comentário? Podes então, por favor, clarificar o cerne da tua pergunta?

Comment: @GuntherSchadow Para melhorar a pergunta, tenta sintetizar a informação (não precisamos de saber todos os passos da pesquisa, apenas os resultados gerais e as dúvidas que estes levantaram). Também seria útil se explicasses o contexto/origem da tua pergunta. Isto tornaria a questão mais clara, concisa e fácil de responder.

Answer (score 0):

Respondendo a "o que você sente" (como falante nativo) quando olha/ouve o nome "Amanda": não faço associação alguma com a etimologia da palavra ou sua semelhança com o verbo amar. Acredito que isso seja ainda mais verdade para os falantes nativos em geral que, ao contrário de quem participa desta comunidade no StackExchange, não são necessariamente interessados na análise da língua.

O que sinto em relação ao nome tem relação às pessoas chamadas Amanda que conheci ao longo da vida, tal como o que sinto em relação a "Lucas". Pessoalmente, sinto algo relacionado à etimologia ou significado de um prenome somente em dois casos: quando é idêntico a uma palavra em português (por exemplo, o prenome "Feliz"), ou quando já me me interessei e pesquisei sua etimologia (a partir de então, começo a fazer a associação).

Contribuindo para sua lista de possíveis significados para "Amanda" que um falante nativo sem conhecimento formal do portugês ou de outras línguas poderia ter se tentasse procurar-lhe um significado intuitivamente, sem dicionários, eu adicionaria o significado "aquela que está sendo amada".

Answer (score -2):

"amanda" é por vezes usado erroneamente (talvez seja correto no Brasil) para "manda" com significado de "throw" em inglês.

https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/amandar/23626

Comment: Bem-vindo ao site, JoPaGo! Se estiveres falando do verbo “amandar”, ele existe e tem vários significados [https://dicionario.priberam.org/amandar]. Outra coisa: o Gunther estava perguntando sobre o substantivo próprio “Amanda”, não sobre o verbo “(a)mandar”, mas estás bem-vindo ao site de qualquer modo!